# Xcode 4.5 Link-time code gen hangs the linker

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, linker

I'm encountering an issue in when trying to use link time code optimization in Xcode on my iOS project.  Once the link phase starts, it runs until it locks up the machine and it needs to be restarted at the power button.  I'm using XCode 4.5.1 and LLVM 4.1, though the same problem occurs when using GCC instead.  All works fine when LTCG is off.  Has anyone else encountered this?